# Parents names in their passport are not matching the names in my passport. What is the impact on B2 visa?

Tags: visa, names

I am from India. And I am working in USA on H1B visa.

Due to clerical mistake my father education documents have different last name than his original. Same carried to his job documents also.

Where as other set of documents like birth certificate, residence certificate etc.. has his original surname. The original surname carried into my all documents. When I was applied passport I got with original surname and my father name also printed with original surname.

Later recently we have applied passport for my parents. Since the documents required for applying passport are carrying the other last name, they got other than original surname in their passport. So now the last name for my parents in my passport and their passports are different.

Now I am planning to sponsor B2 visa to USA for them. So my specific questions are

1. How much this issue impacts on B2 visa approval?
2. If there is impact what are the remedies to subside it? And what additional documents are required to get approval for B2 visa?

Answer (score 6):

You do not submit anything to USCIS to get approval for B2 visa. USCIS doesn't approve any visas, that's the State Department's job. Specifically - the US consulate at which your parents are going to apply.

Your story sounds plausible and these things happen. If they ask about the discrepancy (if...) - just have your parents explain it as it is. The best remedy would be to correct the clerical mistake, but it is likely an unfeasible task.